# Calculate per category and define class name accordingly

Tags: r, data.table, classification, stat, quantile

The data is like this:

```
temp <- data.frame(type = c("a","b","c","d"), value=runif(100, 10, 2380))
temp <- as.data.table(temp)

# type      value   
# 1:    a 2250.33013   
# 2:    b 1271.71251  
# 3:    c 2299.45486   
# 4:    d  807.30089  
# 5:    a   31.32157
```

I would like to calculate quartile per type, then define class as class1,2,3,4 per division.

My goal is to evenly distribute class value among different type.

My first quick approach was like this,

```
a <- temp[type == "a"]
b <- temp[type == "b"]
c <- temp[type == "c"]
d <- temp[type == "d"]

quantile(a$value)
quantile(b$value)
quantile(c$value)
quantile(d$value)

dt <- temp[, quantile := quantile(value), by = type]
```

And then create `dt$class <- ifelse(...)`

But this seems like a detour way to solve this problem. I feel like I could use apply sorts of technique here, but haven't been able to find related subjects yet.

My ideal outcome should be something like this(ignore the numbers for this)

```
# type      value   quantile            class
# 1:    a 2250.33013   31.32157         class1
# 2:    b 1271.71251  112.83298         class2
# 3:    c 2299.45486   33.67312         class3
# 4:    d  807.30089   40.06302         class4
# 5:    a   31.32157  535.78510         class1
# 6:    b  815.11432  808.63388         class2
# 7:    c 1341.02811 1128.15997         class3
# 8:    d  964.20982  650.42241         class4
# 9:    a 2208.44555 1290.29102         class1
# 10:    b 1167.64278 1369.88565        class2
# 11:    c  349.35402 1526.66226        class3
# 12:    d  643.73551 1073.49396        class4
```

So that, ultimately, I would have evenly distributed classes across the type. Please share me your idea to do this in smarter way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you could use the `cut`function as follows:

```
temp[, quant := quantile(value), by = type
     ][, clas := cut(value, 
                     unique(quant), 
                     labels = paste0('class',1:4), 
                     include.lowest = TRUE), 
       by = type]
```

which gives you:

```
> temp
     type      value      quant   clas
  1:    a 2078.94314  129.56675 class4
  2:    b 1360.65024  107.40551 class2
  3:    c 1753.82409   91.92594 class4
  4:    d 1384.85250  149.01646 class4
  5:    a  653.64766  456.96086 class2
  6:    b 1925.33187  565.15271 class4
....
 95:    c 1460.56660 1676.58185 class3
 96:    d  673.59436 1314.27001 class2
 97:    a 1147.94976 2203.73669 class3
 98:    b  648.93761 2317.71071 class2
 99:    c 1341.69222 2328.16911 class2
100:    d  149.01646 2268.54346 class1
```

If you are only interested in the `clas`-variable, you also do:

```
temp[, clas := cut(value, 
                   quantile(value), 
                   labels = paste0('class',1:4), 
                   include.lowest = TRUE), 
     by = type]
```

---

On a side note: When providing sample data with random value generators (like `sample`, `runif` or `rnorm`) it is better to use `set.seed()`. Furthermore: it is better not to give your variables the same name as the functions (hence the use of `quant` and `clas` in my answer).

**Used data:**

```
set.seed(26042017)
temp <- data.table(type = c("a","b","c","d"), value = runif(100, 10, 2380))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `dplyr` to group by type and then rank within groups using `ntile`. No need to convert `temp` to a data table.

```
library(dplyr)
temp <- data.frame(type = c("a","b","c","d"),
                   value=runif(100, 10, 2380))
temp %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(class = ntile(value, 4)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 100 × 3
     type     value class
   <fctr>     <dbl> <int>
1       a  347.7757     1
2       b  789.0118     2
3       c  952.6286     2
4       d  826.3092     1
5       a  378.6079     1
6       b  136.0738     1
7       c 1742.9738     4
8       d 1788.1156     3
9       a 1133.6740     3
10      b 2283.8092     4
# ... with 90 more rows
```